# Invalid path alias

Tags: config, siteurl, alias

I'm not sure if I understand the alias concept entirely

So I want to create an alias.

I write a variable into my `.env` File:

```
SITE_URL_DE="http://hello.local"
```

Then I put it into my `general.php` File:

```
'*' => [
    //other settings as well here
    'aliases' => [
      '@myNewAlias' => getenv('SITE_URL_DE'),
    ],
  ],
```

Now I want to print it in my template:

```
{{ alias('@myNewAlias') }}
```

This results in:

> Invalid path alias: @myNewAlias

But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set it without an `@`

```PHP
'*' => [
    'aliases' => [
        'myNewAlias' => getenv('SITE_URL_DE')
     ]
]
```

Then you can do

```TWIG
{{ alias('@myNewAlias') }}
```

or in PHP

```PHP
Craft::getAlias('@myNewAlias');
```